# Kill slc debug process on OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, debugging, process, node-inspector

How can I quit slc debug?

I have another terminal open where I typed:

```
slc debug
```

It responded:

```
Node Inspector is now available from http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858
Debugger listening on port 5858

Starting the interactive shell (REPL). Type `.help` for help.
The module in the current directory was not loaded: Cannot find module '/Users/razoyo-dev/Thinkster/f2lapper-news'.
Didn't want to start REPL? Run `slc debug .` instead.
```

I can see a > prompt, but I cannot type anything in the terminal.  I tried looking in the Activity Monitor to see if I could find a process to kill, but I cannot tell which is the right one.  (I see three node applications.  I assume it’s one of them.)

I suppose I could reboot my machine, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

To kill the process, you can close the terminal window or press Control-C.

Comment: Believe it or not, at the time I wrote the question, I could neither type Control-C in the terminal (I couldn't type anything in the terminal) nor close the terminal window.  Eventually, something changed so that I could.  Yup.  I know I sound crazy.  But that's what happened.  Also, I don't know what changed, so I don't have anything useful to answer.  Regardless, NobodyNada, thank you for the response.